# how to connect sql server 2008 from my android app

Tags: android, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I'm developing android app to connect SQL Server 2008, and this is my source code 
DBConn.java

```
public class DBConn {
    private static Connection conn = null ;
    private static String DRIVER = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String DB_NAME = "TestDB" ;
    private static String DB_USER = "sa" ;
    private static String DB_PASSWORD = "sa" ;

    public boolean conSqlServer() {
        Log.d("ERR","start connect SQL SERVER") ;

        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
            String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.100:1433/TestDB; instance=SQLEXPRESS; user=sa;password=sa";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
            Log.d("SUCCESS","Connection successful ");
            return true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d("ERR","ERROR CONNECTION 1 = " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false ;
        }
        catch (Exception ex ) {
            Log.d("ERR","ERROR CONNECTION 2 = " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false ;
        }
    }
}
```

i call this from MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
....
....
    DBConn dbconn = new DBConn();
    dbconn.conSqlServer() ;
...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
    .....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    .....
</manifest>
```

but i got error like this

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
at com.noh.connectdb.app.core.DBConn.conSqlServer(DBConn.java:35)
at com.noh.connectdb.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
....
....
```

- I run from android device via wifi
- I check connection my device can ping server
- firewall closed
- port 1433 is opened

can any one help me ?

Comment: Connecting to your database from within your app is a NOGO.
I don't know what you are trying to achieve but use an API instead. if i got your app i can easily hack your Database by reverse engineering your application.

Comment: i just try to connect sql server from my app that it works or not, but it shows error like that, is there any way to fix